# How to re-order a dataframe based on the first non-zero value of each row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe of sales of stores opened in different dates, with the columns being months. I want to reorder the dataframe so that the columns go for 1st month since opening, 2nd month since opening... This is so that I can comparer 1st month performance for each store. The dataframe is something like:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[0.0, 0.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0],
                   [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 3.0, 1.0, 1.0, 7.0, 0.0],
                   [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 15.0, 16.0, 17.0, 18.0]
                  ]
                  , columns=['Jan-19', 'Feb-19', 'Mar-19', 'Apr-19', 'May-19', 'June-19', 'Jul-19', 'Aug-19'])

I want it to be something like:

     A    B     C     D     E     F     G     H
0  3.0   4.0   5.0   6.0   7.0   8.0   
1  3.0   1.0  1.0   3.0    7.0  0.0    
2  15.0  16.0  17.0  18.0
```

I have tried the following to iterate over each row and find the first non zero value:

```
# define a function to find the first non-zero value in a row
def first_non_zero(row):
    for val in row:
        if val != 0:
            return val
    return 0

# apply the function to each row of the DataFrame
df['first_non_zero'] = df.apply(first_non_zero, axis=1)
```

I am more unsure about how to go about re-ordering the whole dataframe. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

**Code**

```
cond = df.cummax(axis=1).ne(0)
out = df[cond].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x[x.notna()].tolist()), axis=1).rename(lambda x: chr(x + 65), axis=1)
```

out:

```
    A       B       C       D       E       F
0   3.0     4.0     5.0     6.0     7.0     8.0
1   3.0     1.0     1.0     7.0     0.0     NaN
2   15.0    16.0    17.0    18.0    NaN     NaN
```

Comment: Thank you! How would you modify this if I had rows for costs, sales, salary costs and I wanted to re-order them all by the first time the store has sales? So reordering all the rows corresponding to the Store A according to its row Sales?

Comment: @bbbb please don't change the logic **after** asking the question and receiving several answers, this is not fair. If you have a follow-up ask a new question.

Comment: no worries! apologise, will ask a different question!

Answer (score 1):

Simple approach using a boolean mask and [`cummax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cummax.html):

```
out = df.apply(lambda s: s[s.ne(0).cummax()].reset_index(drop=True), axis=1)
```

Alternatively, using [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy) for a vectorial approach:

```
# convert to array
a = df.replace(0, float('nan')).to_numpy()
# identify leading 0s/NaNs
m = np.minimum.accumulate(np.isnan(a), axis=1)

# move NaNs to the end, convert back to DataFrame
out = (pd.DataFrame(a[np.arange(len(df))[:,None], np.argsort(m, axis=1)])
         .dropna(how='all', axis=1)
       )
```

Output:

```
      0     1     2     3    4    5
0   3.0   4.0   5.0   6.0  7.0  8.0
1   3.0   1.0   1.0   7.0  0.0  NaN
2  15.0  16.0  17.0  18.0  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: Super nice! Works amazing, if I had to do it for a subset of columns, would you just do df1 = df1.drop(['A', 'B'], axis=1) and then apply the functions to the subset and join?

Comment: @bbbb yes, or put them in the index temporarily

Answer (score 0):

By [shift](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html)ing values leftwards based on [first_valid_index](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.first_valid_index.html) position:

```
(df.replace(0, np.nan)
 .apply(lambda x: x.shift(-x.index.get_loc(x.first_valid_index())), axis=1))
```

---

```
   Jan-19  Feb-19  Mar-19  Apr-19  May-19  June-19  Jul-19  Aug-19
0     3.0     4.0     5.0     6.0     7.0      8.0     NaN     NaN
1     3.0     1.0     1.0     7.0     NaN      NaN     NaN     NaN
2    15.0    16.0    17.0    18.0     NaN      NaN     NaN     NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible approach, which is based on the idea of first converting the elements of the dataframe to `string` and then using `regex` to remove the leading `0.0`:

```
(df.astype(str).map(lambda x: x + ' ')
 .sum(axis=1).str.replace(r'^[0.0\s]*', '', regex=True)
 .str.split(expand=True).astype(float)
 .set_axis(list('ABCDEF'), axis=1))
```

Output:

```
      A     B     C     D    E    F
0   3.0   4.0   5.0   6.0  7.0  8.0
1   3.0   1.0   1.0   7.0  0.0  NaN
2  15.0  16.0  17.0  18.0  NaN  NaN
```